# How to use single file components in render function

Tags: vue.js

I have a select box as a single file component.  I have another component that renders a table but uses the render function.  If I import the the select box how do I use it as a child inside the render function?  I've tried 'h(selectbox)' but the variable 'selectbox' is not accessible inside the render function (undefined).

```js
    // table.js
    import selectbox from '@/components/selectbox'

    export default {
      components: { selectbox },
      render(h) {
        /* 
        ** some table elements rendered here
        */
        let td = h('td', {}, /* insert selectbox component */)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have declare it as a local component you can use:

```js
h('selectbox')
```

`h` aka `createElement` is the way to create the VNode. When a template contain:

```html
<selectbox />
```

The vue compiler will transform it to the above code.

In your case you have to do it like this:

```js
let td = h('td', {}, [h('selectbox')])
```